# how get pk in get_absolute_url recursively

Tags: django, python-3.x

By using inlineformset I've created a createview, all is working very well but, I need to redirect the user to the created author detail view.

> How can I get the author id using the get_absolute_url in the model
>   Book?

I will explain in the following code what I've made.

> Firstly, I have two models with a relationship, Author and Book.

```
class Author(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField("Description", max_length=150)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        "Book",
        verbose_name=_("Book"),
        on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Author")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Authors")


class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Book Name", max_length=150)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Book")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Books")

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('author-detail', args=(need author pk here,))
```

> Here, I have the formset.

```
AuthorFormSet = forms.inlineformset_factory(
    Book,
    Author,
    form=AuthorForm,
    fields = ['description'],
    extra=2
)
```

> And here I have my view.

```
class BookAuthorCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Book
    fields = ['name']
    template_name = "core/formset.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(
            BookAuthorCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs
        )
        if self.request.POST:
            data['formset'] = AuthorFormSet(self.request.POST)
        else:
            data['formset'] = AuthorFormSet()

        return data

    def form_valid(self, form, *args):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        authors = context['formset']

        with transaction.atomic():
            self.object =  form.save()

            if authors.is_valid():
                authors.instance = self.object
                authors.save()

        return super(BookAuthorCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Your modeling looks weird, since now it means that an `Author` can write *one* book, and each book belongs to zero, one or more `Author`s.

Answer (score 0):

The modeling looks a bit "off". You here made a `ForeignKey` in the `Author` model that points to a `Book` (and that foreign key is named `author`). This thus means that, according to your modeling. An `Author` writes *exactly* one `Book`, and a `Book` can be written by zero, one or more authors.

The rest of your forms and views also seem to swap the two. For example you make a `BookAuthorCreateView` with as model a `Book`, but you seem to create `Author` objects here. It would probably help if you currently do not care much about the relations, and try to implement forms for the `Book` and `Author` individually.

Likely you want the reverse relation, as in that a `Book` has an author. You can write this as:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField("Description", max_length=150)
    # no author foreign key

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Author")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Authors")


class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Book Name", max_length=150)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        'Author',
        verbose_name=_('Author'),
        on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Book")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Books")

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('author-detail', args=(self.author_id,))
```

You can then use, `self.author_id` to retrieve the primary key of the related `Author` object.

It is still a bit odd that you specify as "*model url*" for a `Book`, the detail page of the `author`, and not of the book itself.

Comment: Hi, Willem, thanks for your response, I just used this model like a example for what I have here, based on what I have here I need to get the id of the created author.

Comment: @dhelbegor: you get the `id` of the author with `self.author_id`.